# Error when installing package ‘openNLPmodels.de’ in R / RStudio

Tags: r, opennlp

Error when installing package ‘openNLPmodels.de’ in R / RStudio

When I try to install package ‘openNLPmodels.de’ in RStudio I get the following error messages. I run Win7, Java 8 and the latest versions of RStudio an R. openNLP and openNLPdata are correctly installed. Can you help me to install the package? Thank you very much in advance!!! Dominik

Frist alternative: Installation by R:

---

```
> install.packages("openNLPmodels.de", repos = "http://datacube.wu.ac.at/", type = "source")
Installing package into ‘\\xxx/R/win-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://datacube.wu.ac.at/src/contrib/openNLPmodels.de_1.5-2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 8393712 bytes (8.0 MB)
downloaded 8.0 MB

"\\xxx"
CMD.EXE wurde mit dem oben angegebenen Pfad als aktuellem Verzeichnis gestartet.
UNC-Pfade werden nicht untersttzt.
Stattdessen wird das Windows-Verzeichnis als aktuelles Verzeichnis gesetzt.
* installing *source* package 'openNLPmodels.de' ...
** inst
** help
No man pages found in package  'openNLPmodels.de' 
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
*** arch - i386
Warnung in library(pkg_name, lib.loc = lib, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE)
  there is no package called 'openNLPmodels.de'
Fehler: Laden fehlgeschlagen
Ausführung angehalten
*** arch - x64
Warnung in library(pkg_name, lib.loc = lib, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE)
  there is no package called 'openNLPmodels.de'
Fehler: Laden fehlgeschlagen
Ausführung angehalten
ERROR: loading failed for 'i386', 'x64'
* removing '\\xxx/R/win-library/3.2/openNLPmodels.de'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.4/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "\\xxx\R\win-library\3.2" C:\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpy035U7/downloaded_packages/openNLPmodels.de_1.5-2.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘openNLPmodels.de’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpy035U7\downloaded_packages’
```

---

Second alternative: Installation as local package, that I downloaded before from the datacube-website.

---

```
> install.packages("C:/Temp/openNLPmodels.de_1.5-2.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
Installing package into ‘\\xxx/R/win-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
"\\xxx"
CMD.EXE wurde mit dem oben angegebenen Pfad als aktuellem Verzeichnis gestartet.
UNC-Pfade werden nicht untersttzt.
Stattdessen wird das Windows-Verzeichnis als aktuelles Verzeichnis gesetzt.
* installing *source* package 'openNLPmodels.de' ...
** inst
** help
No man pages found in package  'openNLPmodels.de' 
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
*** arch - i386
Warnung in library(pkg_name, lib.loc = lib, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE)
  there is no package called 'openNLPmodels.de'
Fehler: Laden fehlgeschlagen
Ausführung angehalten
*** arch - x64
Warnung in library(pkg_name, lib.loc = lib, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE)
  there is no package called 'openNLPmodels.de'
Fehler: Laden fehlgeschlagen
Ausführung angehalten
ERROR: loading failed for 'i386', 'x64'
* removing '\\xxx/R/win-library/3.2/openNLPmodels.de'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.4/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "\\xxx\R\win-library\3.2" "C:/Temp/openNLPmodels.de_1.5-2.tar.gz"' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C:/Temp/openNLPmodels.de_1.5-2.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Answer (score 0):

My question is solved now. If anybody else will have the same problem, here is the solution:

I installed R and RStudio on  C:\programs.... Because I have no right to write on C:\programs directy, I installed all packages in another network-place Y:\R.... Somehow the installation process has problems to handle with the network.

I deinstalled R and RStudio completely and installed everything again (software and packages) under C:\tools\R... Now every installation runs very fast and I have even no problems with openNLPmodels.de anymore!

Cheers RDominik